# Incorrect tikzpicture size when using dvisvgm output driver (PGF/TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf, dvisvgm

I want to produce an SVG file with a node shape, e.g. rectangle. I use the following LaTeX code:

```
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm.def}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{white}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (start) [draw, rectangle, minimum width=24mm, minimum height=16mm] {How are you?};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and then I use xelatex and then dvisvgm to produce the SVG file:

```
xelatex -no-pdf -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory .\ test1.tex & dvisvgm -n -o .\test1.svg test1.xdv
```

Unfortunately, the produced SVG file has a background object with larger width than the width of the rectangle, resulting in a TikZ picture with larger width. The width is depended on the text width, i.e., if the text is short, the resulting background object width is not longer than the rectangle width, and there is no problem. But when the text width is longer than some critical length, the tikzpicture width is not the same as the drawn object width. Also, I noticed the same problem with the height. In the following example, the problem appears on the top of the tikzpicture:

```
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm.def}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\pagestyle{empty}             % do not remove
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{white}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (point1) [coordinate] {};
  \node at (0,-3cm) (start) [draw, color=black, rectangle, minimum width=24mm, minimum height=16mm] {How are you?};
  \draw (point1) -- (start);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with the following command to be executed:

`xelatex -no-pdf -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory .\ test3.tex & dvisvgm -n -o .\test3.svg test1.xdv`

I am using: Windows 11 MiKTeX-XeTeX 4.10 (MiKTeX 23.5) dvisvgm 3.0.4 pgf 3.1.10

I am expecting the produced SVG file to contain the correct sized objects.

Comment: In both your examples the text fits in the node rectangles, so I see no problem. Note that by default, dvisvgm crops the output SVG to the visible objects in the page.

Comment: @AlexG I corrected the code, because I copied it incorrectly. However, the problem is not if the text is fit inside the rectangle, but the size of the tikzpicture, or the border of the whole tikzpicture is not on the rectangle.

Comment: Ah I see the problem. There seems to be an issue with Pgf's `dvisvgm` driver. With the Postscript output driver `\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvips.def}` I get the correct result (SVG with correct bounding box).

Comment: Maybe you file a bug report at https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf ?

Comment: @AlexG it looks as if there is an hardcoded 1in in the driver, probably to compensate the offset. As soon as the picture is larger than 1in x 1in the svg dimensions are ok.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think I found a fix. There seems to be a conflict between forced bbox setting by `pgfsys-dvisvgm` and automatic computation by `dvisvgm`.

Comment: bug report https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1275

Comment: @AlexG I had filed the bug report github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1275, and it is already answered and corrected.

Comment: I know :). It was me who answered. Though #1275 has not been closed yet.

Comment: @ChristosSevastiadis Btw, if the answer below was helpful and solves your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark on its left side.

Comment: @AlexG, I didn't know that you are the same person :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a graphical object (node, shape etc.) is inserted using `\box...`, PGF's output driver first pushes the final output dimensions by inserting a `dvisvgm:bbox ...` special with the correct dimensions of the inserted TeX box. However, `dvisvgm` itself computes and re-dimensions the output by examining the content of the inserted material. This should be prevented in case of forced bbox adjustment.

Here is a fix for the `pgfsys-dvisvgm` driver which places `dvisvgm:bbox lock` and `dvisvgm:bbox unlock` specials around the `\box...` command. It prevents further bounding box computations during DVI processing by `dvisvgm`.
Typeset with

```bash
latex example
dvisvgm --font-format=woff2 --exact --zoom=-1 example
```

or

```bash
xelatex --no-pdf example
dvisvgm --font-format=woff2 --exact --zoom=-1 example.xdv
```

The `dvisvgm` option `zoom=-1` makes the SVG responsive in order fill the available display size of the Web browser. It makes the effect of the proposed fix more obvious.

For comparison: [SVG with driver fix](https://agrahn.gitlab.io/svg/texsx-695802-with-fix.svg) and [SVG without driver fix](https://agrahn.gitlab.io/svg/texsx-695802.svg).

```latex
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm.def}

\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   fix bounding box setting of inserted tikz objects   %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\def\pgfsys@typesetpicturebox#1{%
  \pgf@ya=\pgf@shift@baseline\relax%
  \advance\pgf@ya by-\pgf@picminy\relax%
  %
  %
  \advance\pgf@picmaxy by-\pgf@picminy\relax% maxy is now the height
  \advance\pgf@picmaxx by-\pgf@picminx\relax% maxx is now the width
  \setbox#1=\hbox{\hskip-\pgf@picminx\lower\pgf@picminy\box#1}%
  \ht#1=\pgf@picmaxy%
  \wd#1=\pgf@picmaxx%
  \dp#1=0pt%
  \leavevmode%
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@trimleft@final\relax  \ifdim\pgf@xa=0pt \else\kern\pgf@xa\fi%
  \raise-\pgf@ya\hbox{\ifpgf@sys@svg@inpicture\else\special{dvisvgm:bbox \pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@picmaxx\space\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@picmaxy}\special{dvisvgm:bbox lock}\fi\box#1\ifpgf@sys@svg@inpicture\else\special{dvisvgm:bbox unlock}\fi}%
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@trimright@final\relax \ifdim\pgf@xa=0pt \else\kern\pgf@xa\fi%
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{white}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (start) [draw, rectangle, minimum width=24mm, minimum height=16mm] {How are you?};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```