# Linear-gradient background in tikz differs when compiled in Xelatex than PdfLatex

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

When compiling the MWE below with `PDFLatex` the linear-gradient color background appears, however when compiled in `XeLatex` the background is white.

- (NB: using `[fill]` produces the salmon color background)
- The linear-gradient is produced with `tikz` with `\path` (\node` also experiences the effect).
- The tex file has previously compiled in `XeLatex` correctly, so perhaps my local configuration is incorrect (it is a recent reinstall of MikTex and TexStudio) or perhaps a tikz issue.
- The compilation is via TeXstudio's built-in commands. MiKTeX Console has updated to the latest packages.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| pdflatex --version | MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.16 (MiKTeX 23.10) |
| xelatex --version | MiKTeX-XeTeX 4.10 (MiKTeX 23.10) |
| TeXstudio | TeXstudio 4.0.2 (git 4.0.2) |

| Compiled with xelatex | Compiled with pdflatex |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=0.9cm, right=0.9cm, vmargin=0.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{backgroundcolor}{HTML}{00264B}

% -- Background color:
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
opacity=1,
angle=0,
contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \path [fill, top color = backgroundcolor, middle color = backgroundcolor, bottom color = backgroundcolor!50] (-10.5,9.9) rectangle (10.5,15) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
}


\begin{document}
\section{Section head}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{document}
```

Some related Xelatex tikz color issues:

- https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+xelatex
- [Incorrect tikzpicture size when using dvisvgm output driver (PGF/TikZ)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695802/incorrect-tikzpicture-size-when-using-dvisvgm-output-driver-pgf-tikz)
- [Gradient color in Xebaposter header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478111/gradient-color-in-xebaposter-header)
- [Tikzpicture blur show up incorrectly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445248/tikzpicture-blur-show-up-incorrectly/445321#445321)

Comment: your document errors.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer - I've removed the `\node` line and cropped the thumbnails (the outcome remains as reported).

Answer (score 1):

It will work if there is second page. If you have only one page you can force the creation of the shading object by storing it once in a box:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=0.9cm, right=0.9cm, vmargin=0.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{backgroundcolor}{HTML}{00264B}

% -- Background color:
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
opacity=1,
angle=0,
contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \path [fill, top color = backgroundcolor, middle color = backgroundcolor, bottom color = backgroundcolor!50] (-10.5,9.9) rectangle (10.5,15) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
}


\begin{document}
\section{Section head}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 

\setbox0\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \path [fill, top color = backgroundcolor, middle color = backgroundcolor, bottom color = backgroundcolor!50] (-10.5,9.9) rectangle (10.5,15) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

**As a workaround**, it is possible to overlay an image file with its own linear-gradient (0% alpha to 35% alpha-white). E.g. the header's linear-gradient becomes:

```
\path [fill=backgroundcolor] (-10.5,9.9) rectangle (10.5,15); # fixed color
\node [inner sep=0pt] (russell) at (-8.7,13.5) {\includegraphics{linear_gradient.pdf}}; # gradient overlay
```